# Coderbytes Letter Changes (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, block

Here is the assigned problem:

> Using the Ruby language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.*

I figured I'd attack this in two parts, however I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with the first half of the problem!

Here is my code as it currently stands.

```
def LetterChanges(str)

  str.downcase!
  str = str.split(//)
  alphabet_lower = ["a".."z"]

  i = 0
  letter = 0
  while i < str.length - 1
  if alphabet_lower[letter] == str[i]
    str[i] = alphabet_lower[letter + 1]
    i += 1
    letter = 0 ## Added this for the instance when letter > 0 after an 'else'
  else
    letter += 1
  end
  end

  str = str.join("")
  return str 

end
```

This code is having infinite loop. I did try a few other things such as

```
......
i = 0
alphabet.each do |letter|
if str[i] == letter
str[i] = letter.next ##I also tried letter + 1
i += 1
end
end
......
```

Comment: How exactly doesn't your code work? Be specific, show an example of input and how it's not working.

Comment: Ah sorry! I am getting what I believe is an infinite loop.

The string input is "Argument goes here"

All I get in the console is "Running your code.........."to infinity.

I don't understand what in my code would cause such a loop for at some point i will equal str.length. I've walked through it in my head a million times.

Comment: also @Cary Swoveland. Thanks! So i've fiddled with the code some, and I've been running it through nitrous.io. I started from the ground up, running little tests to see if the current code is working. This is where I am at. [GitHub](https://github.com/cjpasch/LetterChanges_Ruby/blob/master/LetterChanges.rb)....No letter change is occurring yet, just checking to see if my iteration is working. As you will see my loop is getting hub up on non letter characters. I am not sure how to get past this using basic formatting and methods as I am trying to do.
Sorry for the long wait before replying.

Comment: Could you please use the edit link to fold the additional information into the question itself?  The question should stand on its own, without needing the comments (comments are somewhat transitory).

Answer (score 1):

```
alphabet_lower = ["a".."z"]
```

This creates an `Array` of a single `Range` element, not what you expected. This is the reason `alphabet_lower[letter] == str[i]` is never true, causing infinite loop.

Change it to:

```
alphabet_lower = ("a".."z").to_a
```

Since there is also whitespace character in your string, it's better be:

```
alphabet_lower = ("a".."z").to_a + [' ']
```

Comment: also @Cary Swoveland. Thanks! So i've fiddled with the code some, and I've been running it through nitrous.io. I started from the ground up, running little tests to see if the current code is working. This is where I am at. [GitHub](https://github.com/cjpasch/LetterChanges_Ruby/blob/master/LetterChanges.rb)....No letter change is occurring yet, just checking to see if my iteration is working. As you will see my loop is getting hub up on non letter characters. I am not sure how to get past this using basic formatting and methods as I am trying to do. Sorry for the long wait before replying.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your `if alphabet_lower[letter] == str[i]` doesn't get a match, thus your `letter` increments to infinity, and you get an infinite loop. You can verify this by adding a `puts` on your `else`. It would help if you do as Yu Hao said and place your input and it's output. Also, kindly post the calling script for your `LetterChanges`.

As for the Socratic Way:
The question left, is why does your `if alphabet_lower[letter] == str[i]` doesn't get a match? And how can you get around with it? :)

Comment: its not getting a match when the stri[i] becomes a non letter character.

Answer (score 0):

@Yu has explained your problem. Here's another way that uses the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that uses a hash to substitute each character in the string.

All the work will be done by the following hash:

```
H = ('a'..'z').to_a.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| k }) do |c,h|
  h[c] = case c
         when 'z' then 'A'
         when 'd', 'h', 'n', 't' then c.next.upcase
         else c.next
         end
end
  #=> {"a"=>"b", "b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"E", "e"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h",
  #    "h"=>"I", "i"=>"j", "j"=>"k", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"O",
  #    "o"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s", "s"=>"t", "t"=>"U", "u"=>"v",
  #    "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"A"}
```

The construction of the hash is straightforward, except possibly the line that creates it, which is an argument of [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
Hash.new { |h,k| k }
```

This creates an empty hash with a default value. Specifically, if `h` does *not* have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value `k`. We can see how that works:

```
H['a']      #=> "b" 
H['d']      #=> "E" 
H['%']      #=> "%" 
H['3']      #=> "3" 
H['zombie'] #=> "zombie"
```

This allows us to write:

```
def convert(str)
  str.gsub(/./, H)
end
```

which produces the desired results:

```
convert 'bcd tuv'   #=> "cdE Uvw" 
convert 'bcd3?tuv'  #=> "cdE3?Uvw" 
convert '123D ghi$' #=> "123D hIj$"
```

Note that if we created `H` without the default:

```
H = ('a'..'z').to_a.each_with_object({}) do |c,h|
  h[c] = case c
         ...
         end
end
```

the hash mapping would be the same, but we would obtain:

```
convert 'bcd tuv'   #=> "cdEUvw" 
convert 'bcd3?tuv'  #=> "cdEUvw" 
convert '123D ghi$' #=> "hIj"
```

which is not what we want.

Comment: I understand about 75% of this. So originally I thought about solving this problem with a hash, but went with arrays because I've used them more.  However--although I would like to understand how and why your code syntax works--I would like to try to solve these problem with less refractored methods.
Background: I've only completed 70% of CodeAcademy's Ruby course.
 In other words, is there a way to write out your method of using a hash with beginner level syntax. Thanks and sorry for the slow response! I appreciate your reply.